# Loop across ports (avr)

Tags: avr, embedded, c

I am trying to scan a key matrix that is 9 rows long. Currently my code is a bunch of if statements, one per row, and I would like it get it down to a small if loop. I don't think I can put PINB, PIND, etc in an array as that would just store the current contents of the PIN, right?

Here is the code I'm trying to condense:

```
static inline uint64_t Buttons_GetStatus(void)
{
  uint64_t currentStatus = 0;

  // Scan the matrix, one column at a time
  for (uint8_t column = 0x00; column < 0x06; column++)
  {
    PORTB |= COLUMNS_ALL;
    PORTB &= ~(0x01 << column);
    if (!(PINB & 0b01000000))
    {
      currentStatus |= matrix[0][column];
    }
    if (!(PINB & 0b10000000))
    {
      currentStatus |= matrix[1][column];
    }
    if (!(PIND & 0b00000001))
    {
      currentStatus |= matrix[2][column];
    }
    if (!(PIND & 0b00000010))
    {
      currentStatus |= matrix[3][column];
    }
    if (!(PIND & 0b00000100))
    {
      currentStatus |= matrix[4][column];
    }
    if (!(PIND & 0b00001000))
    {
      currentStatus |= matrix[5][column];
    }
    if (!(PIND & 0b00010000))
    {
      currentStatus |= matrix[6][column];
    }
    if (!(PIND & 0b00100000))
    {
      currentStatus |= matrix[7][column];
    }
    if (!(PIND & 0b01000000))
    { 
      currentStatus |= matrix[8][column];
    }
  }

  return currentStatus;
}
```

and I want it to look something like this:

```
static inline uint64_t Buttons_GetStatus(void)
{
  uint64_t currentStatus = 0;

  // Scan the matrix, one column at a time
  for (uint8_t column = 0x00; column < 0x06; column ++)
  {
    PORTB |= COLUMNS_ALL;
    PORTB &= ~(0x01 << column);
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
      if (!(rows[row][PIN] & rows[row][BIT]))
      {
        currentStatus |= matrix[row][column];
      }
    }
  }

  return currentStatus;
}
```

In case it helps, I am working with an example from the LUFA library and this code is in my custom Buttons.h file for my board.

Comment: Note that if you are pushing wto buttons at the same time, the output will be the one with the highest row index; maybe it's what you want, but be sure about it

Comment: clabacchio - I am ORing all the pressed keys together, so I don't see why only the highest row index one will stick. My existing code (the top sections) performs exactly as I want, but I just thought the code could look better. AlexZam - Thanks for the answer. Are you suggesting I create a second loop for PINB? I had considered this, but I would still like to condense to one. I suppose I could store all 9 PIN states in a larger variable and loop through that. I will try these out when I get back to my dev hardware.

Answer (score 1):

```
pinVal = (PIND & 0b01111111);
for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
  if (pinVal & 0x1) {
    currentStatus |= matrix[row+2][column];
  }
  pinVal = pinVal >> 1;
}
```

And then same for `PINB`.